# change any rule in codeigniter to match function

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have set up my routes.php to suit the nature of my site. Unfortunately, there is a problem with my last route i.e.:

```
$route['(:any)']     = "profile/profile_guest/$1";
```

If the username password name passed is correct, for e.g. domain.com/username, it will load his/her data. if not, it loads the page with errors (because failure to retrieve data with non-existent user in database). This is my problem! I want to avoid this error showing.

Is there anyway I could avoid this error from happening? None of the echoes seems to be printing or the redirect neither is working. Don't know why! it is as if the code inside this method is not executing and the view is loaded instead. below is part of the profile_guest function:

```
public function profile_guest($username)
    {
            $username = $this->uri->segment(1);
            //echo "Hello " . $username;
                redirect('main', 'refresh');
            if($username != '')
            {
                /* echo "<h1>HELLO WORLD SOMETHING</h1>"; */
```

Comment: Maybe the username is outside of `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` located in `config.php`. What kind of errors are you getting? Is it the 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code.

Maybe you need to check the value before running the query:

```
// user_model
function get_user($username = NULL){
    if($username){
        return $this->db->query(...
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then check that the query returned anything before loading the view

```
if($this->user_model->get_user($username){
    //show the page
}else{
    echo "no user found";
}
```